# newcommand which computes something

Tags: macros

I would like to have a command which executes a simple division of numbers.
This `\newcommand{\mylen}[1]{1.0 / #1}` just prints `1.0 / 3` when invoked as `\mylen{3}` and not the desired `0.33333`. What do I have to do?

**Edit:** The result should be usable in an expression like `\includegraphics[width=\mylen{3}\textwidth]{a}`

Comment: For the simple usage using `\dimexpr` is OK. For something more complicated, you might want to use `luatex. See the section on [Arithmetic without using abacus](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Programming_in_LuaTeX#Arithmetic_without_using_an_abacus) on the ConTeXt wiki.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want this for lengths then it is easy,

```
\the\dimexpr 1pt/3\relax
```

produces `0.33333pt`. If you don't want the explicit units then the simplest way is to first add `pt` then remove it from the result.

Or there are several packages that do more exact floating point arithmetic, notably `pgf` or `fp` or `l3fp`

Comment: I would like to use the result in an expression like `\includegraphics[width=\mylen{3}]{...}` or actually with `\setkeys{Gin}{width=\mylen{3}\textwidth}` :)

Comment: [width=\dimexpr\textwidth/3] is all you need in that case